# Can i use Elementary with the laptop close?

Tags: settings, laptop, dell

Im using a Dell G3 3590 laptop, and I want to use it to work, but I would like to use my 2 monitors and have the laptop closed, do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.
You'll just have to edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and change the default behaviour for the lid sensor.
Open Terminal and type

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

input your password, and look for the line containing **HandleLidSwitch**. Uncomment it and replace `suspend` with `ignore`, so that is looks like this:

[image]

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to save the file, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to close the editor. Now all that's left is to apply the new configuration with:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
```

Now, when you close the lid, the laptop will no longer enter suspend.